# Temporarily saving a list of IDs (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have an app where a User can create a Message. They must choose their recipients from Contacts in the database. When the Message is published, the selected Contacts are used to create MessageRecipients. Here is a simplified example of the models in the app:

```
from django.db import models


class Message(models.Model):
    DRAFT = 0
    PUBLISHED = 1
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (DRAFT, 'Draft'),
        (PUBLISHED, 'Published'),
    )
    message = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)


class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class MessageRecipient(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='messages')
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='recipients')
```

If the user saves the Message as a draft and decides to leave the form, I want them to come back and see that the Contacts they had previously selected are preselected for them. They also might want to change their choices, so I think it would be best to avoid creating the MessageRecipient instances until the Message has been fully submitted and published. I think this means that I have to save a list of Contact PKs attached to the Message while it is a draft. Any suggestions on a way to temporarily save this list of Contact PKs?

Comment: Why not just add a field to your `Message` model, something like `state` (choice between draft/sent/something else) or `is_draft`?

Comment: I edited my code to show that I am already saving the 'status' of the Message, that's not the problem. I am just not sure how to save a list of Contact PKs attached to the Message.

Comment: Then my original question stands--why not just use that? I mean, does it really matter if you have recipients created before sending the message? If you want to run reports on recipients having "received a message", you can join onto the Message model and check its status (e.g., `MessageRecipient.objects.filter(message__status='Published')`), no?

Comment: I just want the user to be able to leave the form after saving it as a draft and when they come back, the contacts they had selected will be preselected for them.

Comment: Again, that can be accomplished by allowing them to save `MessageRecipient` models to the database. It's just a matter of checking the `Message` model's status in order to display it as a draft or published. Obviously your view code should only send the message as an e-mail when the user has sent the message (i.e., it's no longer a draft). Saving a list of `Contact` pks gives you no advantage and in fact will slow you down because you'll have to do two separate queries. Instead save the `MessageRecipient` models and take advantage of database joins.

Comment: And if they decide to remove Contacts from their list of recipients that have already been created as MessageRecipients, do I just delete the corresponding MessageRecipient?